# Laravel Model get all where $id = Auth::user()->id

Tags: php, laravel, controller

How to List all rows from a DB where $id matches the logged user id.
I'm using default Auth from Laravel.

At the moment i can list them all with this method in my controller:

```
public function index(){

    $invoices = Invoice::all();
    return view('index', compact('invoices'));
}
```

But i just want the ones that are from this user which is logged in:

Something like

```
$invoices = Invoice::where('id', '=', Auth::user()->id);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code Seems almost right. I would do:

`$invoice = Invoice::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->get();`

So basically use the `get` in order to fetch a collection. And maybe I would separate the user id in a varaible in case that you change the authentication in the future ;)

Comment: Oh this is done without '=' and with ->get(); Thank you @Umbert P.

Answer (score -1):

When using any condition then of course you must need to add the `get()` method. Otherwise, you can't show your data.

```php
$invoices = Invoice::where('id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

This means that you want to see data on which user is logged in now